# Can I combine many annotations with common parameters

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I am having some trouble with creating an @interface which combines some others in it.
For an example I want to create an @Interface and pass a parameter to it which will automatically be given/passed to its "parents".

As far as I know, this can not be done. But I am still curious if there is anything I could do.

```java
@Entity(name = "categories")
@Where(clause = "deleted=0")
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE categories SET deleted = 1 WHERE id = ? AND version = ?")
public class Category extends BaseEntity {
```

In the code above you can see that the parameter "name" which has value "categories" is used in the Entity annotation and it is also contained in the string of the SQLDelete.

Doing this, I want to make the code more readable, and avoid having too many Annotations which are the same for all of the entities I have. Also if I need to change an annotation for all of them to be able to make it easier.

Comment: `deleted=0` and `deleted = 1`... is it a typo?

Comment: you could write own annotation `@SQLDelete(template = "UPDATE #entity.name SET #where.clause WHERE id = ? AND version = ?")`, put it over the parent class, and in the children, by other annotations, you would provide arguments to that template. At runtime, you would need to parse the template, add Hibernate's `@SQLDelete` with a rendered result to the children, which looks like a tedious piece of work.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko That helped me a lot. Didn't think about that. I was thinking of making another interface which extends the JpaRepository, and override the delete method, using the "entityinformation" (JpaEntityInformation<T, ?> entityInformation;)
Thanks!!

Comment: That sounds more sensible:)

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Just added as a comment some code. Thanks again!

Comment: Don't post it as an answer, please. Edit your question.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko why not? Just got me confused. haha

Comment: Because it doesn't answer your question, does it? Some people may downvote it.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Lol, you are right somehow. It doesn't answer my question, but it solves one of the "problems" I was trying to solve by this. Anyways, I deleted it.